# limit proof involving functions

Tags: limits

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are real valued functions in an interval $D$ if c $\epsilon$ $D$, and if the $\lim{c\to 0}$ $f(x)$ and  $\lim{c\to 0}$ $g(x)$ exist and show that $\lim{c\to 0}$ $(f(x)+g(x))$ = $\lim{c\to 0}$ $f(x)$ + $\lim{c\to 0}$ $g(x)$.

I remember learning that this is true in calc 1, but we never proved it. any hints or help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Ok a hint. Apply the definition of limit for $\varepsilon/2>0$ to $f$ and $g$. Take $\delta>0$ appropriate in such a way that you can apply the triangular inequality to $$|[f(x)+g(x)]-(L_1+L_2)|,$$ where $L_1$ and $L_2$ are the limits of $f$ and $g$, respectively.